# Get related youtube videos by a certain uploader

Tags: php, youtube-api, zend-gdata

For a youtube brand channel I need to find related videos **only** from the owner of that channel.

I use the `Zend_Gdata_YouTube` class. To search for videos by category or keywords I'am using the function `getVideoFeed`:

```
$this->yt->getVideoFeed('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/'.self::UPLOADER.'/uploads?category=' . $category)
```

for related videos I'am creating a new video query and set the feed type to related:

```
$ytQuery = $this->yt->newVideoQuery();
$ytQuery->setFeedType('related', $videoId);
```

I've searched everywhere but can't figure out how to set the uploader in the video query, nor how to create the right link for the video feed. However, there is the method `setUploader` that only accepts *partner* as parameter.

Is there any possibility to get related videos uploaded by a certain user, or do I have to write a function by my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, the answer is a mix of all parts I already used and tried:

```
$query = $this->yt->newVideoQuery();

$query->setFeedType('related', $videoId);
$query->setMaxResults(4);
$query->setAuthor(self::UPLOADER);

$feed = $this->yt->getVideoFeed($query);
```

the direct API call would be:

```
$url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'.$videoId.'/related?max-results=4&author='.self::UPLOADER;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoQuery();
$q->setUploader($value);

$videos = $yt->getRelatedVideoFeed($videoid, $q);
```

Comment: The setUploader method only excepts 'partner' as parameter. when I try your code, I get: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Unknown value for uploader'.

Comment: this will return the same results, videos of many other users too. thanks though.